# Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 network interfaces won't keep static IP

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, vmware, static-ip

I'm using VMware with Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 LTS VM.

I have two network interfaces connected to the VM; the first one ens33 is connected to NAT and provides the internet connection to the server. The second one, ens34, is a network interface that is supposed to be used to connect other machines to the server.

Now, I'm trying to set up static IP for the interfaces. I have edited via `sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces` and added

```
auto ens33
allow-hotplug ens33

iface ens33 inet static
address 192.168.42.140
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 192.168.42.1

auto ens34
allow-hotplug ens34

iface ens34 inet static
address 192.168.241.140
netmask 25.255.255.0
```

The problem is that when rebooting the server it applies random IP addresses and not the one I've chosen in the file.

If I run the command `sudo ifdown --force ens33` to switch off the interfaces I got the messages

```
RTNETLINK answers: No such process
RTNETLINK answers: Cannot assign requested address
```

But when I run `sudo ifup ens33` I have no error and with `ifconfig` I can see my network card ens33 having the right IP I've assigned at the beginning

What am I missing?

PS the goal to assign static IPs to the interfaces is that I would like to connect another VM to my server and share the internet connection of the server with the VM/s connected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was static IPs on Ubuntu Server 20.04.2 must be configured with Netplan

Navigate to `/etc/netplan` and edit the file `.yaml` or create your own with

```
network:
    version: 2
    ethernets:
        ens34:
            addresses: [192.168.241.132/24]
            gateway4: 192.168.241.129
            nameservers:
                addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
```

Full reference https://netplan.io/examples/